# Facebook login/logout status in android app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

I'd like to have Facebook login in my Android app. So, I managed to organize sign in using `Facebook Login Button` and registering `FacebookCallback`. Now we have access to public Profile info and so on. Here is my question:

> In Facebook account `Settings > Security` there is an item called `Where You're Logged In` where you can `End Activity` in all devices that are logged in. **How can we get info about user's decisions here? (if user chose to `End Activity` on some devices)**

There we have classes like `ProfileTracker` and `AccessTokenTracker`, but it seem they can't help. Or I used them incorrectly.

And another one, but connected to the previous.

> If a user changes, for example, her name. It seem have no effect on `Profile` in my app. **Can we get info about user's name changes? (if a user changes her name using, for example, another app)**

**Edit:** Currently I have the following code. But it does not respond on `End Activity` on Facebook webpage. Or maybe it should only respond on local changes (if user logouts from Facebook on the device).

```
// ...
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // Start tracking access token changes
    accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(
                AccessToken oldAccessToken, 
                AccessToken currentAccessToken) {
            if (currentAccessToken == null || currentAccessToken.isExpired()) {
                // Force logout
                LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
            }
        }
    };
    accessTokenTracker.startTracking();
}
// ...
// ...
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // Stop tracking access token changes
    accessTokenTracker.stopTracking();
    super.onPause();
}
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

[AccessTokenTracker](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/AccessTokenTracker/) features `onCurrentAccessTokenChanged()` is what you should hook to to be notified about token revocation

> It seem have no effect on Profile in my app.

You may clear local profile yourself once you are notified access is revoked:

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
```